Launching android app through an activity with intent filter causes icon to change and app name to be "Google Play services"
12/06/2024:
My issue specifically was caused by scanning the QR code with the native QR reader app on my phone. Switching to a different QR reader app and scanning actually causes my app to open correctly.

I am developing an android app using the Avalonia UI framework. I believe this is unrelated to the actual problem, but I don't know for sure.
I've added an activity to my project, so the app will launch when I click a certain link or scan a QR code. The app opens correctly when I use a link or scan a QR code, but:

The icon of the app, when displayed in the app drawer, changes to the "Google Play services" icon
The display name of the app, when displayed in the app drawer, changes to "Google Play services"

I couldn't find anything regarding this odd behaviour, so I'm hoping for answer here.
My goal is that the icon and the display name remain constant and don't change to something else.
This behaviour only happens when the app starts through the activity. Manually starting the app causes no issues or odd behaviours.
My activity class in C# :
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Name = "com.Test.MyApp.StartAppActivity", MainLauncher = false)]
public class StartAppActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}

The code inside my AndroidManifest.xml:
<application android:label="MyApp"  
             android:theme="@style/SplashScreen_Theme" 
             android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_foreground" 
             android:logo="@mipmap/launcher_foreground" >
    
    <activity android:name="com.Test.MyApp.StartAppActivity" 
              android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_foreground"  
              android:exported="true"  
              android:label="MyApp">
        
        <intent-filter android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_foreground">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="MyAppScheme" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    
</application>


Why do you need the icon in the <intent-filter> i.e. android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_foreground"

I don't think I need it, I had just added it in an attempt to keep the icon from changing.

I think that's messing with things, you should remove it from places where it's not necessary

It sounds like you're only experiencing this behaviour when deep-linking into your application meaning Google Play Services is likely creating an intent to open your StartAppActivity when you click the link/scan the QR code and is therefore retained as the parent task. You should look into Android Launch Modes, which will tell the Android OS how you would like your activity to open (whether that's through an intent like a deep-link or via the launcher).
Assuming that I have understood your problem correctly, adding launchMode="singleTask" to your AndroidManifest.xml under the Activity tag should resolve the problem, like so:
    <activity android:name="com.Test.MyApp.StartAppActivity" 
              android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_foreground"  
              android:exported="true"  
              android:launchMode="singleTask"
              android:label="MyApp">

I would also recommend, if possible that you should try to use the onNewIntent() override in your MainActivity rather than having StartAppActivity launch your MainActivity, this should work very well with the singleTask launch mode. You can read more about that here.

I think your general advice here is solid so I`ll accept it as the answer. I want to note though that this alone didn´t solve my issue.
It turns out that the native QR scan app that I used caused my problem. Scanning my code through a different QR app actually correctly starts my app instead. Clicking on a link pointing to my custom URI from Chrome also works correctly.
The native QR reader always caused only the OnCreate() function to be called, the other app and the browser both trigger onNewIntent() instead, which then opens my app corerctly

@MelonDusk Yes, this is due to what I've explained in my post.
Each app will generate the intent slightly differently e.g. some will add an activity flag (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) to the intent which will bring about the behaviour you're expecting whereas some will not add the flag(s) leading to inconsistent behaviours.
The only way to ensure it's working correctly all the time is to ensure your launch modes are set correctly in your manifest to handle it as you wish i.e. a separate task entirely.

I sort of understand the problem, I just don´t really understand how to fix it, or at least it isn´t working for me. The launchMode is set to "singleTask" and I´m using my MainActivity to handle the activity.
Scanning my url with the native QR tool always triggers OnCreate(). From there I can see the incoming Intent being the one I set up in my manifest. Am I supposed to add the missing flags there and then manually call OnNewIntent() or StartActivity() with the new intent?

I believe there are a few different issues going on so let me try to summarise:
The QR code app(s) generate intents, one QR code app may be adding a NEW_ACTIVITY flag (for example), whereas the other isn't and therefore the behaviours may be different based on which QR code app you are using, hypothetically.
Secondly, you have StartAppActivity which I believe you don't need - you can add the launchMode property to your MainActivity and then handle the intent inside of onNewIntent() in the MainActivity, which should hopefully resolve your issue(s)

Thanks for taking the time to respond.
I have changed my setup so the the activity I use to launch the app uses the MainActivity. The launchMode for my MainActivity is also set to "singleTask".
When you say "handle the intent", what do you mean? I am overriding the onNewIntent() function in my MainActivity, but this method never gets called from scanning with the native QR reader app. Instead, I only receive calls to OnCreate(). I have tried manually calling OnNewIntent() from OnCreate(), with my Intent + added flags as the parameter, but either nothing changes or it just crashes my app

@MelonDusk please read through this section of the Android docs thoroughly: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode, it perfectly explains the issues you're describing. onNewIntent is only called if there is an instance of your MainActivity is already running, if there's not an instance running already, it will indeed call the onCreate so you need to make sure that you handle the intent in both the onCreate and onNewIntent, I hope this clears up the confusion. You should update the launchMode depending on how you would like your app to handle it.
